# how to set chmod permission in java jsch channelsftp setPermission(int permission, String path)

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

How can I convert a chmod value like 755 so it fits in channelSftp setPermission(int permission, String path)?

I can't figure it out. :(

EDIT:
Here it says I'm suppose to use a bitmask. But I'm not sure how that would be done either.
http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpATTRS.html#setPERMISSIONS(int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Permission perm = new Permission();
//set the permissions you want.
setPermission(perm.getDecimalCode(), path);
```

You can get the Permission class from here:

http://svn.cyberduck.ch/tags/release-2-3/source/ch/cyberduck/core/Permission.java

Comment: How do I set the permissions to "perm"?

Comment: sorry, forgot to attach the class!!

Answer (score 1):

```
channelSftp.chown(0755, f.getName());
```

Comment: Did you mean chmod instead of chown?

Comment: This works, but as KevinS notes, Max meant "chmod", not "chown".

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's digging up an old grave but I have better solution - SftpChannel.chmod expects decimal integer while unix format (644, 777 etc.) is octal. All you have to do is simple conversion:

SftpChannel.chmod(Integer.parseInt(""+, 8), path);