# How to change file permission in sftp using java

Tags: java, sftp

I need help in changing the permission of file  in the remote server using sftp

```
String serverFileName = "FileInServer.txt";   
sftp.upload("src/test/java/com/visa/filecreation/testfile/"+fileName+".txt",serverFileName);
```

Using Java I need to change the permission of file to owners read and write, but not for groups and others.

Required in this format

> :::FileInServer.txt

Rights are

> rw- --- ---

currently, the file permission on the remote server is

> ::FileInServer.txt

Rights are

> rw- r-- r--

Comment: Could it be an owner problem? The SFTP user not being the regular user or in a group of the regular user? Then not a **chmod** but **chown** (change owner) / **chgrp** would make sense.

Comment: There is already a similar question to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582444/how-to-set-chmod-permission-in-java-jsch-channelsftp-setpermissionint-permissio

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [ChannelSftp.chmod](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#chmod-int-java.lang.String-)

```
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
channelSftp.chmod(511,"path");
```

Comment: `chmod(511,"path");` The number should be in octal, i.e. `0511`.